# dijit tree checkbox select all the child when parent clicked

Tags: checkbox, dojo, tree

I have created check box adjacent  to each node of the tree using _createTreeNode. The fiddle link given below:

http://jsfiddle.net/pyz9Lcpv/8/

Now my requirement is below:
1. get all the treenode name when "try it" button clicked. I am trying this using publish and subscribe. Pushing the the treenode name in javascript array when checked and when unchecked, looping through the array and splice it from the array. Is there any other better way to capture the checked node?

2. Another requirement is, when the parent node is checked, all the child node should also gets checked. I have observed that the argument "checkbox" contain the child elelment so I have list child node name , but I am not able to check these child node checkbox. Please help me in resolve this issue.

Please find the Jsfiddle link code:

```
HTML:
 <div id="contentHere">
</div>
<div id="contentButton">
    <button>Try it</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
      require([
    "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel", 
    "dijit/Tree", "dijit/form/CheckBox",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(win, Memory, ObjectStoreModel, Tree){

    // Create test store, adding the getChildren() method required by ObjectStoreModel
    var myStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            { id: 'world', name:'The earth', type:'planet', population: '6 billion'},
            { id: 'AF', name:'Africa', type:'continent', population:'900 million', area: '30,221,532 sq km',
                    timezone: '-1 UTC to +4 UTC', parent: 'world'},
                { id: 'EG', name:'Egypt', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                { id: 'KE', name:'Kenya', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                    { id: 'Nairobi', name:'Nairobi', type:'city', parent: 'KE' },
                    { id: 'Mombasa', name:'Mombasa', type:'city', parent: 'KE' },
                { id: 'SD', name:'Sudan', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                    { id: 'Khartoum', name:'Khartoum', type:'city', parent: 'SD' },
            { id: 'AS', name:'Asia', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
                { id: 'CN', name:'China', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
                { id: 'IN', name:'India', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
                { id: 'RU', name:'Russia', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
                { id: 'MN', name:'Mongolia', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
            { id: 'OC', name:'Oceania', type:'continent', population:'21 million', parent: 'world'},
            { id: 'EU', name:'Europe', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
                { id: 'DE', name:'Germany', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
                { id: 'FR', name:'France', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
                { id: 'ES', name:'Spain', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
                { id: 'IT', name:'Italy', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
            { id: 'NA', name:'North America', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
            { id: 'SA', name:'South America', type:'continent', parent: 'world' }
        ],
        getChildren: function(object){
            return this.query({parent: object.id});
        }
    });

    // Create the model
    var myModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
        store: myStore,
        query: {id: 'world'}
    });

    // Create the Tree.
    var tree = new Tree({
        model: myModel,
        getIconClass:function(item, opened){
                console.log('tree getIconClass', item, opened);
                console.log('tree item type', item.type);
            },

        onClick: function(item, node) {
                node._iconClass= "dijitFolderClosed";
                node.iconNode.className = "dijitFolderClosed";
                console.log("node : " +node);

            },
        _createTreeNode: function(args) {
            var tnode = new dijit._TreeNode(args);
            tnode.labelNode.innerHTML = args.label;

            var cb = new dijit.form.CheckBox();
            cb.placeAt(tnode.labelNode, "first");

            dojo.connect(cb, "onChange", function() {
                var treeNode = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(this.domNode.parentNode);
                checkBoxClicked(treeNode.item);
                dojo.publish("/checkbox/clicked", [{
                    "checkbox": this,
                    "item": treeNode.item}]);
            });

            return tnode;
        }
    });
    tree.placeAt(contentHere);
    tree.startup();
    dojo.subscribe("/checkbox/clicked", function(message){
                console.log("you clicked:", store.getLabel(message.item));   
            });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed your code at few places, please have a look.
We can use the dojo.query in multiple ways like finding elements , modifying them etc.

```js
require([
    "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dijit/tree/ObjectStoreModel", 
    "dijit/Tree", "dijit/form/CheckBox","dojo/dom",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function(win, Memory, ObjectStoreModel, Tree, checkBox, dom){

    // Create test store, adding the getChildren() method required by ObjectStoreModel
    var myStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            { id: 'world', name:'The earth', type:'planet', population: '6 billion'},
            { id: 'AF', name:'Africa', type:'continent', population:'900 million', area: '30,221,532 sq km',
                    timezone: '-1 UTC to +4 UTC', parent: 'world'},
                { id: 'EG', name:'Egypt', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                { id: 'KE', name:'Kenya', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                    { id: 'Nairobi', name:'Nairobi', type:'city', parent: 'KE' },
                    { id: 'Mombasa', name:'Mombasa', type:'city', parent: 'KE' },
                { id: 'SD', name:'Sudan', type:'country', parent: 'AF' },
                    { id: 'Khartoum', name:'Khartoum', type:'city', parent: 'SD' },
            { id: 'AS', name:'Asia', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
                { id: 'CN', name:'China', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
                { id: 'IN', name:'India', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
                { id: 'RU', name:'Russia', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
                { id: 'MN', name:'Mongolia', type:'country', parent: 'AS' },
            { id: 'OC', name:'Oceania', type:'continent', population:'21 million', parent: 'world'},
            { id: 'EU', name:'Europe', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
                { id: 'DE', name:'Germany', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
                { id: 'FR', name:'France', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
                { id: 'ES', name:'Spain', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
                { id: 'IT', name:'Italy', type:'country', parent: 'EU' },
            { id: 'NA', name:'North America', type:'continent', parent: 'world' },
            { id: 'SA', name:'South America', type:'continent', parent: 'world' }
        ],
        getChildren: function(object){
            return this.query({parent: object.id});
        }
    });

    // Create the model
    var myModel = new ObjectStoreModel({
        store: myStore,
        query: {id: 'world'}
    });
              
    // Create the Tree.
    var tree = new Tree({
        model: myModel,
        getIconClass:function(item, opened){
             console.log('tree getIconClass', item, opened);
             console.log('tree item type', item.type);
         },
        
        onClick: function(item, node) {
          node._iconClass= "dijitFolderClosed";
          node.iconNode.className = "dijitFolderClosed";
          console.log(node.domNode.id);
    var id = node.domNode.id, isNodeSelected = node.checkBox.get('checked');
    console.log(isNodeSelected);
    
     dojo.query('#'+id+' .dijitCheckBox').forEach(function(node){ 
      dijit.getEnclosingWidget(node).set('checked',isNodeSelected);
     });
    
          
         },
        _createTreeNode: function(args) {
            var tnode = new dijit._TreeNode(args);
            tnode.labelNode.innerHTML = args.label;
   console.log(args);
            var cb = new dijit.form.CheckBox();
            cb.placeAt(tnode.labelNode, "first");
   tnode.checkBox = cb;
            

            return tnode;
        }
    });
    tree.placeAt(contentHere);
    tree.startup();
    tree.expandAll();
    
    
});
  
  function retrievInfo(){
  
   dojo.query('.dijitChecked').forEach(function(node){
  dojo.query('#nodeContent')[0].innerHTML += node.parentNode.parentNode.innerText;
   });
}
```

```html
 <div id="contentHere">
</div>
<div id="contentButton">
    <button onclick="retrievInfo()">Try it</button>
 
</div>
<div id="nodeContent"> </div>
```

Thanks
Srikant

Comment: Thanks this worked. Now I am working on reverse of the requirement i.e. if all the child is checked , then parent should be automatically checked. Please let me know if this requirement can be carter by dojo.query.

Comment: Yes, Same way you can track the child checkboxes and track the parent. You can use node.parentNode to reach out the parent node. Please accept  the original answer.

Comment: Actually my tree is in collapse state initially and only one node need to expand at a time. With above condition i am  not getting the desired result. How can I checked the check box of the child if the parent node is collapse. Do I need to save the checkbox state in database and each time when we expand the node fetch the state value from database.

Comment: The fact is, the tree child tree will be created only  when the parent node is expanded. So as you rightly said please save the current state of the checkbox selections.      Also please use             'var cb = new dijit.form.CheckBox({id: args.item.id});'    now it will be easy to store the checkbox selections in an array and then store it in a DB.   I have updated your jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/pyz9Lcpv/10/